# Daisy chain two monitors on a single thunderbolt port

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, daisy-chaining

I currently have 3 monitors (Asus VN247H) connected to a mid 2014 15" MBP Retina. Two connections are on thunderbolt (with TB->HDMI adaptors) and one on the HDMI port. I would like to use one of the thunderbolt ports for another peripheral. Is there a way to daisy chain two monitors on a single TB port?

Comment: Only if the first screen in the chain is Thunderbolt

Comment: Okay so this setup should be possible if I put a thunderbolt hub as the first device in the chain?

Comment: Short answer.. no. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205191/el-capitan-and-daisy-chaining

Answer (score 1):

You can chain up to 12 thunderbolt devices of any kind. If you want to connect a non-thunderbolt device, make sure you put it at the end of the chain.
Also keep in mind that Apple, for some reason, doesn't allow 3rd party-non-thunderbolt-displays chained *directly* after their own Thunderbolt Display. However it will work if another thunderbolt-device is inbetween.