# El Capitan and Daisy Chaining

Tags: display, displayport, macos

Will El Capitan allow me to daisy chain two Dell 2713H monitors from my 2015 13" MBP? Both monitors support DisplayPort 1.2. Currently if I attempt this my monitors become a new desktop, but they are mirrored. Unable to get the 2nd monitor detected by OS X. Previous research on this topic shows that my MBP technically supports the technology by OS X does not. Anyone know if El Capitan will enable this?

Comment: Probably not, since mac pushes thunderbolt and cinema displays

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but display and Thunderbolt are two different things on the same port. You CAN chain Thunderbolt, you CANNOT chain Display.

Comment: @CousinCocaine it is possible to chain DisplayPort 1.2 devices, and it even works on Macs running Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a 2015 15" running the El Capitan Gold Master and it still mirrors the displays. I wish they'd sort this out, I'm wasting a Thunderbolt port by having to connect both displays independently.

Comment: It mirrors for me also.   Using 2 Acer K272HUL. Called Apple Support and they said using 2 thunderbolt ports for 2 monitors is normal.  Can't use them in daisy chain.   Acer Support says Windows works fine in daisy chain.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one that'll really cook your noodle:
Yes, the hardware in a MBP will support this (I've done it on MacBook Pro 15", mid 2014).

But no, it only works if you're using Bootcamp and booted into Windows.

Apple has chosen not to support this in their drivers and software.

Comment: Lord above, this is so annoying. I'm constantly running out of mDP / TB2 ports!