# Display Daisy-Chaining with High Sierra

Tags: display, high-sierra, daisy-chaining

has this [issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205191/el-capitan-and-daisy-chaining?noredirect=1&lq=1) been sorted out with High-Sierra?

The issue being (in case you didn't want to click the link) that daisy-chained displays were always being mirrored instead of recognised as individual displays.

Comment: I am curious, is this not something you can test yourself by just daisy chaining your monitors?

Comment: I would really like to, but my buying decision depends on whether that is possible or not :D

To be exact it actually is about a docking-station, but from what I read earlier this problem also translates to connecting two monitors to a dock, which in return is connected via one USB-Type-C connection.

Comment: Again...just curious..  So, it's macOS vs Windows depending on support?  It's supported on HW (via Bootcamp).   I'm just trying to wrap my head around the logic behind trying it *without* the dock and if it works/didn't work, you would have a strong answer to post.

Comment: @Allan So basically you are suggesting just daisy-chaining them now to see if it works and then having an answer? The problem is I don’t think I currently have the right cables here to do that. I would have to go from USB Type C to DisplayPort which would require an adapter which then again might be another part of the equation that might fail. Maybe I will get around to doing so eventually, but for now I am just going to wait a little longer if someone might already know the answer :D

Comment: Without knowing your exact model, I can't say what you need exactly, but if it's ***native*** display port, you don't need an adapter, just a cable.  All USBC ports on Macs provide displayport signals.  You just need the cable which you would have to purchase anyway.

Comment: @Allan Since the dock was going to have DisplayPort I would not have to buy a cable in this case. Else you were right, of course :)

Comment: I just bought a second Dell U2515H and tried daisy chaining them to my Macbook Pro '15 High Sierra. No luck, second monitor mirrors the first.

Comment: @RickDoesburg I see :( If you post that as an answer I can give this question closure. Also thanks for the info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just bought a second Dell U2515H and tried daisy chaining them to my Macbook Pro '15 High Sierra. No luck, second monitor mirrors the first.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Windows on to a Bootcamp partition and os has no problems daisy chaining the displays. If i return to OSX i can get only mirrored display on my Dells. The problem is that Apple supports only thunderbolt dasychaining. If you are using display port it has no support (or it disabled, case and point: windows os) for MST displayport connections.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, both of my Dell U2515 are mirror each other. They are connected to the docking station via D-port to D-port and the other D-port to HDMI on the docking station. I have tried many thing to make them work separately but no luck. So frustrating. I have the 15-inch MacBook with touch bar and running high sierra. I was going to try getting thunderbolt-d-port cabled and connect them direct without docking station and see what happen. Thanks

Comment: I currently use an elgato thunderbolt 3 dock and have one monitor connected via displayport and one via usb type-c to hdmi. It actually does work for me. So I am currently quite a bit confused

Comment: @CrazyQwert if one of the monitors is connected to your laptop via a display port and the other via usb-c, then they're not really daisy-chained (connected with each other). Neither does it really count for the issue in question if both are connected to a dock or connection hub.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so now I went ahead and bought a thunderbolt 3 dock to which I have both my monitors connected. They are being recognised as separate monitors. So I guess it does work, but maybe it needs to be thunderbolt 3, since there are still some people on here saying they cannot connect 2 monitors